# How to preallocate Vector in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I made an application which involves mutable graph (I need to be able to modify object referencing each other). For that, I use and id and store each object in a `Vector` (the id of an object being it's position within the vector). The vector is kept in a state and creating a new object is done using a state transformer.
Everything is working fine, however, the creation of each object involves a `snoc`. This lead to bad performance when I load all the objects from a file. Is there a way to allocate the vector with the correct size ? My problem is, I can't use `fromList` because I can only create objects using a smart constructor using a state monad.

The code I have (simplified) is the following

```
data Box = { boxId :: Int , boxName :: String }
data Warehouse = { whBoxes :: Vector Box }

type WH = State Warehouse

newBox :: String -> WH Box
newBox name = do
     warehouse <- get
     let boxes = whBoxes warehouse 
     boxId = Vector.length boxes warehouse
     box = Box boxId name

     put warehouse { whBoxes = boxes `V.snoc` box }
     return box
```

How can read a file and populate the warehouse with boxes using only `newBox` without *snocing* once for each new box ?

## Update

My current function reads a csv containing then name of the box and the number of identical box (I'm using cassava)

```
import qualified Data.Csv as Csv
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazzy as BL
import qualified Data.Vector as Vec

readBoxes :: String -> IO (WH ())
readBoxes filename = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile filename

    case Csv.decode  Csv.HasHeader csvData of
         Left err ->  do putStrLn err; return (return ())
         Right (rows) -> do
                Vec.forM_ rows $ \(style, qty) ->
                       let types = qty :: Int
                       in forM [1..qty] $   \i -> newBox style
```

(As I said earlier, I simplified the code so it might not compile).

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be an improvement, but you could try `V.replicate` to allocate a large vector upfront, and then update it later on.

Comment: "using only newBox" and "without snocing once for each box" are contradictory requirements - newBox hard codes a snoc for each box, if you are not allowed to use any other function other than newBox, you are stuck with one snoc per box. Or perhaps I've interpreted the requirement "using only newBox" too strictly?

Comment: I mean I can rewrite newbox but I would like to keep the same signature (if possible)

Comment: @mb14: what's the context, why do you want to keep the operation or the signature? The current `newBox` is a performance bug for vector building, and its type doesn't support any sensible avenue for correction.

Comment: I like the idea of a having a smart constructor which forbid to create a box outside of a warehouse or let the user assign an incorrect id. I have also different methods of loading boxes from different file format I would like as less refactoring as possible.

Comment: I would guess `constructN` does what you want, but you'll have to restructure the surrounding code somewhat. I can write a bit more about how if you show a bit more of the surrounding code.

Comment: @DanielWagner See my update

Comment: @mb14 Your updated example is too simple to show why you need the `State` machinery: use `data Box = Box String` and later in the case statement use `Right rows -> Vec.concatMap (\(style,qty) -> Vec.replicate qty (Box style)) rows`.

Comment: "Preallocating" an immutable vector doesn't really make sense, even if you allocate a vector with empty values (ie, `Vector.replicate 1000 undefined`), then "fill" it by writing the vector, you still create a copy of the entire old vector when you "write" to that vector. You should simply create a new primitive operation for creating multiple boxes efficiently. Or, just use a data structure which supports this operation (snoc) efficiently, like a list - this choice will depend on what other operations you need. Also, perhaps you need to include the entire specification of the "warehouse" model

Comment: @DanielWagner This is not a XY problem. The fact that I need to use State or not is irrelevant and shouldn't affect the answer. A good reason to keep this state is, the whole application is written that way, and I'm not planning to change it (just to clarify, I'm not at the design state, the program works, and has been there for 6 months. It's just a bit slow (2 or 3 secondes to load 5000 boxes) nothing serious. I was just wondering how I could improve the loading time.

Comment: @user2407038 fair comment. I'm ready to use mutable vector if someone tell me how to to it ;-)

Comment: @mb14 If you are not planning to change anything, you also aren't going to be changing the performance.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not not planing to change anything, I'm just planing to change everything. My point is how can you create a vector efficiency by creating element one by one. All the question about context are irrelevant here.

Comment: @mb14 If you do not know the solution, how can you know what is relevant and irrelevant to the solution?

Comment: @DanielWagner because loading/creating data and using them are orthogonal.

Comment: @mb14 I guess what you're implying is that you are asking a question about loading data, and objecting to us asking questions about data use. But my questions, at least, are about the context of the loading process -- not the context of the use.

Comment: @DanielWagner I misunderstood then. I provide the code of the load function, what context is missing ?

Comment: @mb14 As I said in my previous comment: you should provide enough so that we can see why you need to use `State`. I gave a simple solution for the existing loading code that does not need `State` in the same comment.

Comment: @DanielWagner The reason why I use State is in the "context of use". The main reason is boxes need and Id to be referenced by shelves, which why I put them in a vector. I use a state so that it's impossible to create a box outside a *warehouse* (ie can't create a box which doesn't exist in vector). Anyway, my question is about using State, and why do I need it is irrelevant.

Comment: @mb14 Again, you can't know what is relevant, because you don't know an answer to your question. I don't understand the connection between "using the data requires `State`" and "loading the data requires `State`"; presumably the state can be initialized after loading. I don't understand the connection between "boxes need an ID" and "I must use `State`"; the boxes have an index in the resulting `Vector`, which is an ID, whether that `Vector` is constructed using `State` or not. I don't understand the comment about warehouses at all.

Comment: @DanielWagner. Ok forget about the State. However I still need Box to hold a boxId which is it's position within the Vector. Your solution with `replicate` and `concatMap` doesn't provide that.

Comment: @mb14 It is easy to achieve using `Vec.indexed` or `Vec.imap`.